# No migrations to apply for Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I've added a field in my clients model.

Here's the model:

class Client(models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
position = models.CharField(max_length=30)

organization = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", related_name="clients", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
category = models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="clients", null=True, blank=True, default=6, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)

street_address = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None) 
baranggay = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)
region = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)

date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

phoned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
special_files = models.FileField(blank=True , null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name
```

Before I've added the position field the program runs smoothly.

Now I've got:

ProgrammingError: column clients_client.position does not exist

At Heroku Bash, when I run python manage.py makemigrations, it detects the changes, but when I migrate it says, no migrations to apply.

Please help.